# Mask Image based on another image

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have urls of two images(png). I need to load them and mask one image based on another. 
I am using `fabricjs` library. But I am unable to achieve the desired result so far.
My question is that Is it doable using `fabricjs`? If yes, please point me in the right direction and give some hint.

Thanks.

Comment: Two images in the same position?

Comment: yes, one image over the other.
like the one here http://campratty.com/1faq/faqimage1/mask7b.jpg
upper white image is in png format having the transparent part where the image below(black) is shown.

Comment: I have seen the example using fabricjs here http://resources.aleph-1.com/mask/

Comment: View source code: http://resources.aleph-1.com/mask/js/main.js

Comment: I used the code but its generating an error in 'applyTo' object
maskEl is undefined.
'maskEl = this.mask._originalImage,'

Comment: I think that createClass for the mask is not required with the new version. Check this: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1900

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to use image as a mask in fabricjs. However it is possible to use SVG as a mask either from `SVG String` or `SVG URL`. Here is an example to use SVG as a mask using SVG string.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
});

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas');

var group = [];

fabric.loadSVGFromString('<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Black Shirt</title><metadata id="metadata69503">image/svg+xml</metadata><g><title>Layer 1</title><g id="layer1"><path id="path3287" d="m166.18439,17.37708c-2.03961,0.05794 -4.09917,0.64444 -5.99701,1.79727l-121.55794,73.83949c-6.07317,3.68897 -8.13302,11.78955 -4.62673,18.17904l41.40907,75.46835c3.50636,6.3895 11.22366,8.55663 17.29683,4.86769l63.52823,-38.58598l0,282.00912c0,7.37784 5.65755,13.33011 12.67012,13.33011l234.68106,0c7.0127,0 12.65225,-5.95227 12.65225,-13.33011l0,-282.40228l64.18686,38.97914c6.073,3.68893 13.77252,1.5218 17.27887,-4.86769l41.40912,-75.46835c3.50623,-6.38949 1.44635,-14.49007 -4.62665,-18.17904l-121.54025,-73.83949c-2.46729,-1.49862 -5.21344,-2.02985 -7.82983,-1.70369c-0.50259,-0.0633 -1.01096,-0.09358 -1.53036,-0.09358l-67.22971,0c-0.99521,8.39134 -22.93723,15.10861 -49.80826,15.10861c-26.87125,0 -48.79539,-6.71727 -49.79056,-15.10861l-67.85254,0c-0.40805,0 -0.81207,0.03552 -1.21001,0.07484c-0.50517,-0.05004 -1.00247,-0.08936 -1.51256,-0.07484z" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-width="4.468" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"/></g></g></svg>',function(objects,options) {
    var loadedObjects = new fabric.Group(group);
    loadedObjects.set({
        scaleX:0.5,
        scaleY:0.5,
        lockMovementX : true,
        lockMovementY : true,
        lockScalingX : true,
        lockScalingY : true,
        lockUniScaling : true,
        lockRotation : true,
        selectable: false,
        hasRotatingPoint:false,
        hasControls: false,
        hasBorders: false
    });

    canvas.add(loadedObjects).centerObject(loadedObjects).renderAll();
},function(item, object) {
    object.set('id',item.getAttribute('id'));
    group.push(object);
});

function handleImage(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    //comment out the below code if you want to remove the previous uploaded image
    /*if(canvas.item(1)){
        canvas.remove(canvas.item(1))
    }*/
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
                width:200,
                height:200,
                lockMovementX : false,
                lockMovementY : false,
                lockScalingX : false,
                lockScalingY : false,
                lockUniScaling : false,
                lockRotation : false,
                selectable: true,
                hasRotatingPoint:true,
                borderColor: 'red',
                cornerColor: 'green',
                hasControls: true,
                hasBorders: true,
                transparentCorners: false
            });

            canvas.add(imgInstance).centerObject(imgInstance).renderAll();
            canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(1));

            var shape = canvas.item(0);
            canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
                shape.render(ctx);
            };

            canvas.controlsAboveOverlay = true;
            canvas.renderAll();
        };
        img.src = event.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

There is also one limitation for SVG. If SVG has multiple paths it will only mask the last path. I couldn't find the solution to make it work for all paths of SVG.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aLcb4sb5/)

Comment: Thank you Khawer for putting effort and time in creating fiddle.

Comment: Yes it is not possible to mask two images in fabricjs. I needed to mask one image based on another which I am getting dynamically. I ended up using another library "canvasmask" https://github.com/codepo8/canvas-masking.